# CodeFirst with Migrations to LocalDB, can I specify *where* the DB is created?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, localdb

I've been working on a CodeFirst POCO WPF project and I want the database to be LocalDB. I've used migrations (add-migration and update-database commands in the Package Manager Console window) to generate my database and tables. I've set my config file to have the following connection string:

```
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

With that connection string, after I call *update-database* in the console, it creates the database and all my tables properly, however it puts the MDF file in the root of the currently logged in user. That is the behavior I'm trying to change. I'd like the DB created in the application's folder. How do I do that?

I've tried adding "AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf" to the connection string, but after running update-database I get this error:

```
A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\MyDatabase.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

I get the same error if I try "Initial File Name" instead of AttachDBFileName. It seems like this would only work if the file already exists? But I'd like the file to be auto generated when the user first launches the app, *and* have the file exist in the same folder as the application. How do I go about doing this?

-shnar

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default location for the data file using DataDirectory is in Program Files for Desktop applications. To modify Program Files sub-directories requires that the program run as administrator or that the directory be given the appropriate write-access. See AppDomain.SetData to set the DataDirectory macro to the actual %AppData% directory. Its against Microsoft Best Practices to create data files in Program Files and it usually unnecessary to do so.

Comment: I'm not trying to create it in Program Files. I want it in the user's directory, just not at the root of the user's directory. Installing in the app's folder would be nice, and since it's going to be a ClickOnce app, it won't be in Program Files, it will be in the user's directory. But even if not that directory, ANY directory other than the user's root folder (say {UserDirectory}\AppData\MyFolder)...